# Django models: How to filter by multiple values at once?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm working on a social network project for learning purposes and I'm trying to figure out the best way to make this query:

```
def following(request, user_username):
     user = User.objects.get(username=user_username)
     try:
         following_users = user.following.all()
         following_posts = []
         for following_user in following_users:
             following_posts.append(Post.objects.filter(username=following_user.username))
     except:
         return JsonResponse({"error": "There was an error loading the following posts"}, status=400)
     following_posts = following_posts.order_by("-timestamp").all()
     return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in following_posts], safe=False)
```

I'm trying to get the posts of the users that the user is following in the social media, ordered by reverse chronological order ("timestamp"). And, to do that, I tried first getting all the users that the user follows (`following_users = user.following.all()`) and then getting all the posts these users have one by one (in the for loop). The problem is that the `order_by` function only works with QuerySet, and the `following_posts` is a list. Not only that, I don't think that this is a good way to make this query even if it worked. Can I get all these posts at once without a `for` loop?

Anyway, these are the models that are involved in this query:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    profile_picture = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_568656.png")
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "username": self.username,
            "email": self.email,
            "followers": [user.username for user in self.followers.all()],
            "following": [user.username for user in self.following.all()],
            "join_date": self.join_date.strftime("%b. %d, %Y, %H:%M %p"),
            "profile_picture": self.profile_picture
        }

class Post(models.Model):
    autor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default="", related_name="user_post")
    content = models.TextField(max_length=240)
    likers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="posts_liked")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "autor": self.autor.username,
            "content": self.content,
            "likers": [user.username for user in self.likers.all()],
            "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b. %d, %Y, %H:%M %p"),
            "autor_profile_pic": self.autor.profile_picture
        }
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. If by at once you mean and operation you can use`filter(Q(a=2) & Q(b=2))`. If by at once you mean remove select from the loop, look into `prefetch_related` or `select_related`. If you need to insert at once. use bulk_insert.

Comment: I want to get all the posts made by users that the user follows. By "at once" I mean, how can I filter all the posts that have the autor included in the following_users QuerySet?